# magento - Product page 404 error

Tags: magento, e-commerce

I've copied products from a Magento platform with 1 store to a Magento platform with 2 stores.

After that, the product's page from one category page of 1st store redirects me to a 404 error page.

The product is shown in the admin catalog, and is listed with the other products in the index. But, when I click to see the detailed product, it gives me the 404 page.

I use magento 1.1.7.

Thread closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the Url Rewrtie Section in the admin to see if a rewrite is added for this product that gives you a 404 error.

Answer (score 6):

Go to phpmyadmin and run this command:

Dumping data for table `report_event_types`:

```
INSERT INTO `report_event_types` (`event_type_id`, `event_name`, `customer_login`) VALUES
(1, 'catalog_product_view', 1),    
(2, 'sendfriend_product', 1),    
(3, 'catalog_product_compare_add_product', 1),    
(4, 'checkout_cart_add_product', 1),    
(5, 'wishlist_add_product', 1),    
(6, 'wishlist_share', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check all product entity(Ids) available in "**sequence_product**" table.
Need product id in that table to init product page.